# Construction of external sorts from comparison ones

Tags: java, performance, sorting

Here's an example how to construct an external sorting algorithm from the Quicksort. The method may be applicable to other known internal comparison sort algorithms. I have checked that it shows N*logN time complexity when fed with random file, and almost exactly 0.5 N square when input is already sorted. But I am not sure how to apply external sorts in real life. Maybe someone has a real life problem or test bench for external sort. Is this idea novel at all? So simple. May be parallelizable with some rework.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.RandomAccessFile;
import java.util.ArrayDeque;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Deque;

/**
 * -- Big Q Sort --
 *
 * A variation of Quicksort algorithm for in-place sorting of data that does not completely fit into RAM.
 *
 * The basic idea of this generalization is that pointers used for the partitioning are file block indexes.
 * A step of the original Quicksort algorithm takes two records to compare and conditionally swaps them.
 * This algorithm on the other hand, will take two blocks of records to fill a buffer in memory.
 * Instead of swapping, it runs a sorting algorithm on the buffer and then blocks are written back to the file
 * before the corresponding pointer is moved.
 *
 * Pointers used for the partitioning are file block indexes but pivot is still a single record like in Quicksort.
 *
 * Otherwise the program flow is similar to that of Quicksort.
 *
 * -- This Implementation --
 *
 * Pivot selection saves block reads by selecting a record from the memory, which may not be an optimal pivot.
 * If there are repeated keys, the actual record that plays the pivot role may change while partitioning in this
 * implementation, it is only its key that needs to stay constant.
 *
 * In the demonstration, records are bytes of the file "sort_me.txt", key is the signed value, comparator is <
 *
 * The buffer is assumed to be smaller than the file.
 *
 * The output file will be a multiple of the block size, therefore program adds some null bytes and orders them. In a
 * production implementation this would be bad; but there is no need to complicate this POC to prevent the issue.
 */
public class BigQ {
    private static final int BLOCK_SIZE = 11;
    private static byte[] buffer = new byte[2*BLOCK_SIZE];
    private static final File SORT_ME = new File("sort_me.txt");

    static class BlockInterval {
        long low;
        long high;

        public BlockInterval(long low, long high) {
            assert low < high;
            this.low = low;
            this.high = high;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BlockFile blockFile = new BlockFile(SORT_ME, "rws", BLOCK_SIZE, buffer);

        // divide et impera starts with the whole file as interval to sort
        Deque<BlockInterval> openList = new ArrayDeque<>();
        openList.push(new BlockInterval(0L, blockFile.nBlocks - 1));

        do {
            BlockInterval outerBounds = openList.poll();

            // initial fill of buffer (both halves)
            assert outerBounds.low < outerBounds.high;   // assuming at least 2 blocks span
            blockFile.readBlock(outerBounds.low, BufferHalf.LEFT);
            blockFile.readBlock(outerBounds.high, BufferHalf.RIGHT);
            Arrays.sort(buffer);

            if (outerBounds.low + 1 < outerBounds.high) {
                // interval that does not completely fit into one buffer - partitioning needed
                long doneBelow = outerBounds.low;
                long doneAbove = outerBounds.high;

                // select pivot (does not affect correctness but efficiency)
                int pivotIndex = BLOCK_SIZE - (int)System.currentTimeMillis()%2;
                byte pivotKey = buffer[pivotIndex];

                partitioning:
                while (true) { // buffer is sorted at this point
                    if (pivotIndex >= BLOCK_SIZE) {
                        // left half of buffer contains sub-pivot keys only, pivot is in the right half
                        blockFile.writeBlock(doneBelow, BufferHalf.LEFT);
                        doneBelow++;

                        if (doneBelow >= doneAbove) {
                            // done pointers collide, conclude partitioning by writing out the rest of records
                            blockFile.writeBlock(doneAbove, BufferHalf.RIGHT);
                            break partitioning;
                        }

                        blockFile.readBlock(doneBelow, BufferHalf.LEFT);
                        Arrays.sort(buffer);

                        // by restoring sortedness of the buffer, pivot may have moved some positions left
                        while (buffer[pivotIndex] > pivotKey) {
                            pivotIndex--;
                        }
                    } else {
                        // right half of buffer contains super-pivot keys only, pivot is in the left half
                        blockFile.writeBlock(doneAbove, BufferHalf.RIGHT);
                        doneAbove--;

                        if (doneAbove <= doneBelow) {
                            // done pointers collide, conclude partitioning by writing out the rest of records
                            blockFile.writeBlock(doneBelow, BufferHalf.LEFT);
                            break partitioning;
                        }

                        blockFile.readBlock(doneAbove, BufferHalf.RIGHT);
                        Arrays.sort(buffer);

                        // by restoring sortedness of the buffer, pivot may have moved some positions right
                        while (buffer[pivotIndex] < pivotKey) {
                            pivotIndex++;
                        }
                    }
                }

                // found the final block for the pivot (may still move in the block since the block contains 0 or more
                // lower keys than the pivot, 1 or more pivot keys, and 0 or more higher keys)
                assert doneBelow == doneAbove;

                // when all records of a block are settled, exclude that block from further processing
                if (doneBelow == outerBounds.high && buffer[BLOCK_SIZE] == pivotKey) {
                    doneBelow--;
                }
                if (doneAbove == outerBounds.low && buffer[BLOCK_SIZE - 1] == pivotKey) {
                    doneAbove++;
                }

                // keep partly processed and undone blocks in circulation
                if (doneBelow > outerBounds.low) {
                    openList.push(new BlockInterval(outerBounds.low, doneBelow));
                }
                if (doneAbove < outerBounds.high) {
                    openList.push(new BlockInterval(doneAbove, outerBounds.high));
                }
            } else {
                // degenerate interval of 2 blocks - sort already done in memory, just persist the result
                blockFile.writeBlock(outerBounds.low, BufferHalf.LEFT);
                blockFile.writeBlock(outerBounds.high, BufferHalf.RIGHT);
            }
        } while (!openList.isEmpty());

        blockFile.close();
    }
}

enum BufferHalf {
    LEFT(0),
    RIGHT(1);

    int i;

    BufferHalf(int i) {
        this.i = i;
    }
}

class BlockFile extends RandomAccessFile {
    long nBlocks;
    private final int blockSize;
    private final byte[] buffer;

    // analysis stuff
    static int readCount = 0, writeCount = 0;

    public BlockFile(File file, String mode, int blockSize, byte[] buffer) throws FileNotFoundException {
        super(file, mode);
        this.blockSize = blockSize;
        this.buffer = buffer;
        nBlocks = (file.length() + blockSize - 1)/blockSize;
    }

    public void readBlock(long blockIndex, BufferHalf bufferHalf) throws IOException {
        seek(blockSize*blockIndex);
        read(buffer, blockSize*bufferHalf.i, blockSize);
        readCount++;
    }

    public void writeBlock(long blockIndex, BufferHalf bufferHalf) throws IOException {
        seek(blockSize*blockIndex);
        write(buffer, blockSize*bufferHalf.i, blockSize);
        writeCount++;
    }

    @Override
    public void close() throws IOException {
        super.close();

        System.out.println("N = " + nBlocks);
        System.out.println("N*log(N) = " + nBlocks*Math.log(nBlocks)/0.2);
        System.out.println("N*N/2 = " + nBlocks*nBlocks/2);
        System.out.println(readCount + " reads");
        System.out.println(writeCount + " writes");
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm reading this correctly but you seem to be sorting very small files, and sorting directly on disk.  I don't think that's right.  I'd like to see a test driver that reproduces some of the measurements you took.

Comment: Get a 100 gig file and set a 100 mega buffer size. Then it starts to make sense to sort externally. If I add a bigger structure and a comparator instead of byte comparison, the externalness is more justified but the number of IO won't change. So this is enough 
 for counting block writes. Test was manual. I copied the source code to sort_me.txt and modified the buffer size several times. I got in the output datapoints for a scatter plot and saw the expected trend.